# Reading the MP3 IDV2 tag size

Tags: c, mp3, id3v2, async-safe

I am trying to read the size of a ID3V2 tag. my code is supposed to be storing the the first header which contains the identification, version, flags and size in this struct. The code freads from bit 0 to bit 9 and stores it here

```
typedef struct
{
   uint32_t id:24; //"ID3"
   uint16_t version; // $04 00
   uint8_t flags; // %abcd0000
   uint32_t size; //4 * %0xxxxxxx
}__attribute__((__packed__))
ID3TAG;
```

reads:

```
fread(tag, sizeof(ID3TAG), 1, media);
```

then passes the value of tag.size to this function which unsyncsafe the bits of the size:

```
int unsynchsafe(uint32_t in)
{
    int out = 0, mask = 0x7F000000;

    while (mask) {
        out >>= 1;
        out |= in & mask;
        mask >>= 8;
    }

    return out;
}
```

However the returned value of synchsafe can never be the correct size of just the header. I got 248627840. I double checked using exif tool and it was not correct. I would really appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question. See also [ask]. This is not a code review site.

Comment: You should put the code in your question so that people can see it and copy it easily. Not that this is your problem, but it is a generally bad idea to `typedef` fundamental types, e.g., `typedef uint32_t  LONG`.

Comment: for all complaining about the format of my question I changed it completely. Please take a look at my code.

Comment: ID3V2 is not a pointer it's the name of my new data type struct and it's not the problem I checked and it was returning 10 which is the aimed value

Comment: Sorry @AbdullahEmad, that was a momentary lapse of sanity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having has to do with endianness. I am assuming that you are working on an x86 system, or on another system that is little-endian. The [ID3 documentation](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#References) states that:

> The byteorder in multibyte numbers is most significant byte first (e.g. $12345678 would be encoded $12 34 56 78).

So the `size` is stored as a big-endian number in the file. After you read the bytes of the file into your `struct`, you need to convert this byteorder to little-endian before stripping out the four zero-bits to obtain the final 28 bit representation of `size`. This is also why you had to compare `tag->id` with `0x334449` instead of `0x494433`-- the bytes stored in `tag->id` were accessed as a multibyte value, and interpreted in little-endian order.

Here are the changes I made to make this work. I changed your `struct` a little, using arrays of `uint8_t` to get the correct number of bytes. I also used `memcmp()` to validate `tag->id`. I made liberal use of `unsigned` and `unsigned long` types, to avoid bit-shifting woes. The conversion to little-endian is primitive, and assumes 8 bit bytes.

This is the entire file that you linked to in the first post, with my changes. I changed the mp3 file to something I had that I could test on.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  // for memcmp()

/**
 ** TAG is always present at the beggining of a ID3V2 MP3 file 
 ** Constant size 10 bytes
 **/

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t id[3];       //"ID3"
    uint8_t version[2];  // $04 00
    uint8_t flags;       // %abcd0000
    uint32_t size;        //4 * %0xxxxxxx
}__attribute__((__packed__))
ID3TAG;

unsigned int unsynchsafe(uint32_t be_in)
{
    unsigned int out = 0ul, mask = 0x7F000000ul;
    unsigned int in = 0ul;

    /* be_in is now big endian */
    /* convert to little endian */
    in = ((be_in >> 24) | ((be_in >> 8) & 0xFF00ul) |
          ((be_in << 8) & 0xFF0000ul) | (be_in << 24));

    while (mask) {
        out >>= 1;
        out |= (in & mask);
        mask >>= 8;
    }

    return out;
}

/**
 ** Makes sure the file is supported and return the correct size
 **/
int mp3Header(FILE* media, ID3TAG* tag)
{
    unsigned int tag_size;

    fread(tag, sizeof(ID3TAG), 1, media);

    if(memcmp ((tag->id), "ID3", 3))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    tag_size = unsynchsafe(tag->size);
    printf("tag_size = %u\n", tag_size);

    return 0;   
}

// main function
int main(void)
{
    // opens the file
    FILE* media = fopen("cognicast-049-carin-meier.mp3", "r");

    //checks if the file exists
    if(media == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't read file\n");
        return -1;
    } 

    ID3TAG mp3_tag;
    // check for the format of the file
    if(mp3Header(media, &mp3_tag) != 0)
    {
        printf("Unsupported File Format\n");
        fclose(media);
        return -2;      
    }
    fclose(media);

    return 0;
}
```

Incidentally, there is already a function in the C Standard Library that does this conversion. `ntohl()` is in the `netinet/in.h` header file, and it converts a `uint32_t` number from network byte order (which is big-endian) to host byte order. If your system is big-endian, the function returns the input value unchanged. But if your system is little-endian, the input is converted to a little-endian representation. This is useful for passing data between computers using different byte-ordering conventions. There are also the related functions `htonl()`, `htons()`, and `ntohs()`.

The above code can be changed (for the better) to use `ntohl()` by replacing my primitive conversion code with:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>  // for ntohl()
...
/* convert to host-byte-order (little-endian for x86) */
in = ntohl(be_in);
```

Comment: This is a very good explanation. It really helped me clarify things. Thank's a lot for your time and effort :D

Comment: @AbdullahEmad-- Certainly; I have added some comments to my answer about the Standard Library function `ntohl()` which can be used to convert from big-endian to whatever is appropriate for your system.

Comment: Thank you a million times. I want to make sure I am getting that. According to the id3 documentation the size is divided into 3 bytes. Each byte has a value of zero on it's 7th bit. Does that mean I have to get rid of this 7th zero before passing it to the ntohl( ) function which converts the number to little endian or does the function takes care of that for me ?

Comment: No. The `.size` field is 4 bytes (`uint32_t`). Yes, the high-order bits of each byte are set to zero and ignored. But you do not remove the zeros first, you pass the value stored in the `.size` field, `tag->size`, to the function `ntohl()` first to get the bytes in the right order, then remove the zeros. All you have to do to the above code is `#include <netinet/in.h>`, and replace my bit-shifting code after the `/*convert to little endian */` comment with the single line: `in = ntohl(be_in)`. This converts `be_in` from big-endian to whatever your architecture uses (little-endian in this case)

Comment: The code that you used to remove the zeros in your original program was correct, is still in the code of my answer unchanged, and must remain there to remove the zeros after conversion by `ntohl()` if the program is to work correctly.

Comment: Your question inspired me to implement my own version of `ntohl()`, [which I put on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149717/implementation-of-c-standard-library-function-ntohl). There were some very good comments and links provided, if you care to check it out.

Comment: Yeah sure I will. I finally solved the problem :) however the id3.org site is down and I cannot carry on.